# "syntax error near unexpected token `fi' "

Tags: unix

```
echo process started  
file_name="sample.txt"  
cd /o1_appdata/home/scits/SC1E  
if [ -f ${file_name} ]  
then  
echo "File exists. Document file validation passed.">logfile.txt  
else  
echo "Document file validation failed.">>logfile.txt  
fi
```

Comment: My guess is you are invoking this through something other than `sh`.  Add a shebang.  (`#!/bin/sh`)

Comment: I works for me both with /bin/dash and /bin/bash - please indicate what shell you are using.

Comment: ya you are right @WilliamPursell..after mentioning #!/bin/sh, the code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

The semicolon was missing after if check can you try with this it would be good if you mention if it is `#!/bin/bash` or something else

```
echo process started
file_name="sample.txt"
cd /o1_appdata/home/scits/SC1E
if [ -f ${file_name} ] ;
then
echo "File exists. Document file validation passed.">logfile.txt
else
echo "Document file validation failed.">>logfile.txt
fi
```

Comment: The semi-colon is redundant, and the newline is sufficient to separate the command from the following `then`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell how can you say that when you don't know which shell OP uses?

Comment: The semi-colon is not necessary in any Bourne compatible shell.  The syntax is so wrong for the `csh` family that the semi-colon is irrelevant rather than redundant.